# How to check whether user has granted Start in background permission programatically in android

Tags: android, android-permissions, background-process

In my app I need to have **Start in background** permission enabled

I'm doing this to launch app settings.

```
val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
val uri = Uri.fromParts("package", context?.packageName, null)
intent.data = uri
this.startActivityForResult(intent, START_IN_BACKGROUND_CODE)
```

From there user has to click on **Other permissions** and enable **Start in background** permission

But I **didn't find** any way to check **whether user has already enabled it** for the application

[image: Permissions screen]

Is there any way (like Settings.canDrawOverlays(context) ) ??

Thank you.

Comment: did you find any solution for this?